# Two Different Shape Array Multiply

Tags: python, arrays

How I Can I Solve This Problem operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4579,4579) (2,2) In Two Array  Multiply

I Try  Multiply Two Diffrent Shape Arra

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you aware how [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) works and why it requires the inner dimension to be of the same length? What would the result of the operation for your arrays be?